# How to use Memoization with minimax algorithm for tic tac toe game?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, tic-tac-toe, memoization, minimax

I recently tried to make a tic tac toe ai using the **Minimax** algorithm. It works perfectly. But it took way too long to make the first move. Then I implemented **Alpha Beta pruning**, which made it slightly faster, but still too long. Now I am trying to use **Memoization** or Hash tables, it way more faster now, something wrong happened, previously the ai took perfect moves, but now it makes silly moves.

This has been going on for a some time, but then i did something... Previously all the best moves were hashed, but then i started hashing it only when a certain depth was reached. This made the ai perfect again and dropped the time from 30 seconds to 10 seconds, but still i don't understand why the depth matter for hashing, Also I believe that the algorithm can be even more faster, Most codes I have seen does these in less than 2 seconds.

- I used pygame for rendering
- The state is a Board **class** with various methods for checking win, draw etc:
- The actual board is a attribute of the state --> state.board
- The code for the minimax algorithm is given below

```
import math
import pygame

CACHE = {}


# state: the current board in tic-tac-toe (node)
# depth: index of the node in the game tree

def minimax(state, depth, maximizing_player, max_marker, alpha, beta):
    # Check Cache
    if state.board.tobytes() in CACHE:
        return CACHE[state.board.tobytes()]

    if max_marker == 'X':
        min_marker = 'O'
    else:
        min_marker = 'X'

    if maximizing_player:
        best = [(-1, -1), -math.inf]

    else:
        best = [(-1, -1), math.inf]

    # Evaluate and add Cache
    if depth == 0:
        return [(-1, -1), 0]

    elif state.check_win(max_marker, False):
        return [(-1, -1), 10 + depth]

    elif state.check_win(min_marker, False):
        return [(-1, -1), -10 - depth]

    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if state.board[i, j] == ' ':
                if maximizing_player:
                    state.place_marker(max_marker, (i, j), False)
                    [_, score] = minimax(state, depth - 1, False, max_marker, alpha, beta)
                    state.board[i, j] = ' '
                    if score > best[1]:
                        best = [(i, j), score]
                    alpha = max(alpha, score)
                    if beta <= alpha:
                        break
                else:
                    state.place_marker(min_marker, (i, j), False)
                    [_, score] = minimax(state, depth - 1, True, max_marker, alpha, beta)
                    state.board[i, j] = ' '
                    if score < best[1]:
                        best = [(i, j), score]
                    beta = min(beta, score)
                    if beta <= alpha:
                        break
    # Add Cache
    CACHE[state.board.tobytes()] = best
    return best
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a cache be used for an alpha-beta search algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61958921/can-a-cache-be-used-for-an-alpha-beta-search-algorithm)

Comment: That questions seem to be similar to mine but i don't understand the explanations fully, some code sample would have been nice. Thanks though, it gave me some ideas to try.